# Python API streaming examples for RabbitMQ on Flink

Tags: python, apache-flink

Considering using Flink in place of Spark. Firstly cannot seem to find any examples that use the Python API in a streaming mode. I.e. going here, I don't see any: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming/ option for python

The use case is streaming in flink with RabbitMQ message broker and all with python bindings. Is this possible?

Comment: You maybe can use Java and Python together.

Comment: @linusg sadly we are all python here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink has no Streaming Python API.